# Set kernel.sysrq = 1 in /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf using command?

Tags: editors, magic-sysrq

I wish to use a single command line instead of opening the text editor to change the parameter of the file */etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf* to `kernel-sysrq = 1` from any current parameter, even if other lines are in that file.

Is there not something similar to a *where*?

Comment: @dsstorefilE1 That is just a temporary setting.

Answer (score 1):

```
# sed -i 's+kernel-sysrq =.*+kernel-sysrq = 1+'  /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf
```

Comment: i do not get it

Comment: In the config file, there should line like ```kernel-sysrq =XXX```.

This sed command would replace them into `kernel-sysrq = 1` using `sed` replacing function in form of `s+OLD+NEW+`